# C# Database filter users with listbox

Tags: c#, database, forms, textbox, listbox

So basically, I have set up a database tool which would edit the database.
I also to make it easier added a listbox that shows all names of the people that are in the database.

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni4ol.png)

Anyway. Now I wonder as the list of users can be quite long. How would I add a filter to the listbox?
So if in the textbox above the listbox I would put in "J"
It would only show up with "Joe Weller"

Listbox code:

```
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=password";
        string Query = "select * from altislife.players where name='" + listBox1.Text + "' ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string scash = myReader.GetInt32("cash").ToString();
                string sbankacc = myReader.GetInt32("bankacc").ToString();
                string scoplevel = myReader.GetInt32("coplevel").ToString();
                string smediclevel = myReader.GetInt32("mediclevel").ToString();
                string sblacklist = myReader.GetInt32("blacklist").ToString();
                cash_txt.Text = scash;
                bankacc_txt.Text = sbankacc;
                coplevel_txt.Text = scoplevel;
                mediclevel_txt.Text = smediclevel;
                blacklist_text.Text = sblacklist;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Some random stuff. But that would show what I filled in the code. Not the names anymore.

Comment: Do you use `EntityFramework` or `Ado.Net` ? Is your application is `winforms` or `wpf` or an `asp.net` app?

Comment: Insert your code in your question

Comment: @Mohsen not sure on first question, but i use winforms app. adding code in a few

Comment: How do you fetch data to the list box? directly from the database? Insert your code for adding items to the list box..

Comment: Get the database data into a data holder, have onPropertyChanged hooked up to your textbox and call a function that finds keys in your data holder according to textbox'a value. Then put the function output into an observableCollection that is bound to your listbox. If u want, I can provide some sample code when I get a hold of my PC.

Comment: @Kamil Solecki if you would put in sample code I would appriciate it. I'm quite new to coding and all this what you're saying i only get 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **Entity Framework**

```
using(context db = new Context)
{
    List<User> lu = (from u in db.users where u.Name.StartWith("s") select u ).ToList();
}
```

**Edit**

You are using **Ado.Net**

Sometimes you know one part of value that will match data stored in the table.For example you may need to search for one word within a Description.You can perform search with pattern matching using wild cards to find one value within another value.

**Pattern matching** in possible by using keyword **LIKE**.most of time ,the percent character (**%**) is used along with **LIKE** to represent **any number of characters** And (**_**) used to replace **just one character**

So you need below query string to find user name starts with 's'

```
string Query = "select * from altislife.players where name LIKE 's%'";
```

Comment: Don't want that I don't think. I ment filter. If you put for example put in "J" in a textbox you would see everything starting with a "J" in the listbox